# Place error bar in a barchat

Tags: r, bar-chart, lattice

I want to put add error bars to a simple barchart with lattice but my error bars are overlapped. Here is my code:

First I generate some random data:

```
set.seed(1)
means<-NULL
means$l<- rnorm(20,1,2)
means<-data.frame(means)
means$sd<-rnorm(20,0.1,2)
means$Inoc.size<-c("A","B","C","D")
means$mutation<-c("mut1","mut2")
means
```

then I want to plot one of the variables:

```
barchart(l~mutation, groups=Inoc.size, data=means,
         stderr=means$sd,
         ylab=list(expression(paste("lag phase duration - h")), cex=1.5),
         xlab=list("Mutation",cex=1.5),
         auto.key=list(columns=1, rectangles=TRUE, points=F, at=NULL ),
         scales=list(y=list(alternating=T, tck=c(1,0)),
                     cex=1.2),
         panel=function(x, y, groups, stderr, box.ratio, ...){
           panel.barchart(x, y, groups=groups, box.ratio=box.ratio,origin=0, ...)
           panel.abline(h=0,col="black",...)
           panel.arrows(as.numeric(x),y-stderr, 
                        as.numeric(x), y+stderr,
                        code=3,angle=90, length=0.025)

         })
```

Comment: Any specific reason to use `lattice`? In `ggplot2` you can use `geom_errorbar`which compared to your code looks very simple.

Comment: I have already done it in ggplot2, but in my work we are advice to use preferently Lattice as standard.

Comment: I found a similar question with a solution, it might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383623/adding-error-bars-to-a-barchart-with-multiple-groups

Comment: At least to me, the barchart itself is very unclear, even without the error bars. Why not use a `xyplot` and jitter your error bars as before - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29180567/error-bar-lattice-dotplot/29183794#29183794

Comment: I cannot use a bwplot because this time I have less than 5 samples, and also I tried the Molx suggestion but simply does not work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding error bars to a barchart with multiple groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383623/adding-error-bars-to-a-barchart-with-multiple-groups)